# How to retry Retrofit call on HTTP errors (401) when using RxJava?

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

My current Android Application is employing `Retrofit(2.4.0)` and `RxJava(2.1.16)` to execute my Web Service calls.

Im using Google SignIn for my User Authentication.

I want my Retrofit calls to detect HTTP 401 (UNAUTHORIZED) and attempt to Silently Login with Google Signin
then retry the Retrofit call.

My retrofit calls resemble this

```
@Headers(HEADER_ACCEPT_JSON)
@GET("resources")
Observable<Response<String>> getResources(@Header(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION) @NonNull final String authenticationToken, @QueryMap(encoded = true) @NonNull Map<String, Object> queryMap);



API_SERVICE.getResources(Login.getAuthorizationToken(), id)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(Network::manageResource, Network::handle));
```

From googling I can see that retry/retryWhen will only be triggered when an error occurs in my RxJava chain,
however HTTP 401 errors are not going to raise this condition.

As a newbie to RxJava how can I detect my HTTP 401 code and..

a). Execute Google SignIn Silent login

b). Silent login completes OK, retry my API call?

UPDATE

Ive got closer with the following code

```
@Headers(HEADER_ACCEPT_JSON)
@GET("resources")
Single<Response<String>> getResources(@Header(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION) @NonNull final String authenticationToken, @QueryMap(encoded = true) @NonNull Map<String, Object> queryMap);



API_SERVICE.getResources(Login.getAuthorizationToken(), id)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .flatMap(new Function<Response<Article>,                                           
 SingleSource<Response<Article>>>() {
                        @Override
                        public SingleSource<Response<Article>> apply(final Response<Article> response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "apply() called with: response = [" + response + "]");
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                return Single.just(response);
                            } else {
                                return Single.error(new RuntimeException());
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .retryWhen(errors -> errors.take(1).flatMap(new Function<Throwable, Publisher<?>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Publisher<?> apply(final Throwable throwable) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "apply() called with: throwable = [" + throwable + "]");
                            Login.loginSilently().subscribe();

                            return Flowable.just("DELAY").delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                        }
                    }))
                        .subscribe(Network::manageResource, Network::handle));
```

I do not like the Flowable.just("DELAY").delay() call and also even though I am now catching the exception and silently login in OK I get this exception

```
09-10 16:39:29.878 7651-7718/research.android E/Network: handle: 
    java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSingleSingle$SingleElementSubscriber.onComplete(FlowableSingleSingle.java:116)
        at io.reactivex.subscribers.SerializedSubscriber.onComplete(SerializedSubscriber.java:168)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableRepeatWhen$WhenReceiver.onComplete(FlowableRepeatWhen.java:119)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.drainLoop(FlowableFlatMap.java:426)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$MergeSubscriber.drain(FlowableFlatMap.java:366)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap$InnerSubscriber.onComplete(FlowableFlatMap.java:673)
        at io.reactivex.subscribers.SerializedSubscriber.onComplete(SerializedSubscriber.java:168)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableDelay$DelaySubscriber$OnComplete.run(FlowableDelay.java:139)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
09-10 16:39:29.878 7651-7678/research.android  D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Canceled
```

How can I get the retrywhen to wait for the silentLogin to complete?

and

Whats causing the NoSuchElementException?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember if you have error code > 300 then `onError()` will be called with Throwable which can ba cast to `HttpException` from where you can get error code returned by server so then you can call other function to make some "silent call"

Comment: from my testing when I receive HTTP 401 onError() is not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

To solve 401 Unauthorized Error try to implement AuthInterceptor to your OkHttpClient.

```
BasicAuthInterceptor interceptorAuth = new BasicAuthInterceptor(yourToken);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(interceptorAuth)
        .build();

builder.client(client);
```

If your authToken is expired or bad try to gain new.

```
public class BasicAuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {

private String yourToken;

public BasicAuthInterceptor(String token) {
    this.yourToken = token;
}

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    Request authenticatedRequest = request.newBuilder()
        .header("Authorization", format("token %s", yourToken)).build();

    Response response = chain.proceed(authenticatedRequest);

    boolean unauthorized = response.code() == 401;
    if (unauthorized) {

        Request modifiedRequest = request.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", format("token %s", getNewToken())).build();
        response = chain.proceed(modifiedRequest);
        }

    return response;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize client:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
    .client(createClient())
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .addCallAdapterFactory(ApiHandler(Schedulers.io()))
    .build()
```

Error handler:

```
class ApiHandler(scheduler: Scheduler) : CallAdapter.Factory() {

private val original: RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
        = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(scheduler)

override fun get(returnType: Type, annotations: Array<Annotation>, retrofit: Retrofit): CallAdapter<*, *>?
        = original.get(returnType, annotations, retrofit)?.let { Wrapper(it) }

private class Wrapper<R>(private val wrapped: CallAdapter<R, *>) : CallAdapter<R, Any> {
    override fun adapt(call: Call<R>?): Any? {
        call ?: return null
        val result = wrapped.adapt(call)

        return when (result) {
            is Maybe<*>      -> result.onErrorResumeNext(Function { Maybe.error(wrap(it)) })
            is Single<*>     -> result.onErrorResumeNext { Single.error(wrap(it)) }
            is Completable   -> result.onErrorResumeNext { Completable.error(wrap(it)) }
            is Flowable<*>   -> result.onErrorResumeNext(Function { Flowable.error(wrap(it)) })
            is Observable<*> -> result.onErrorResumeNext(Function { Observable.error(wrap(it)) })

            else             -> result
        }
    }

    override fun responseType(): Type = wrapped.responseType()

    private fun wrap(throwable: Throwable) = when (throwable) {
        is HttpException          -> {
            val exception = ApiException.http(throwable)
            toLog("ex - ${exception.message}")
            exception
        } // We had non-200 http error
        is JsonSyntaxException    -> ApiException.parse(throwable) // We had json parsing error
        is SocketTimeoutException -> ApiException.timeout(throwable) // A network error happened
        is IOException            -> ApiException.network(throwable) // A network error happened

        else                      -> ApiException.unknown(throwable) // We don't know what happened. We need to simply convert to an unknown error
    }
}
}
```

Api exception class:

```
class ApiException internal constructor(message: String,
                                    /** Response object containing status code, headers, body, etc.  */
                                    val response: ErrorResponse?,
                                    /** The event kind which triggered this error.  */
                                    @ApiError val error: Int,
                                    exception: Throwable?) : RuntimeException(message, exception) {

companion object {
    fun http(exception: HttpException): ApiException {
        val response = exception.response()
        var errorResponse: ErrorResponse? = null
        val message = if (response == null) {
            if (exception.message().isEmpty()) exception.code().toString() else exception.message()

        } else {

            // here you can check error code and throw needed exception

            val errorBody = response.errorBody()?.string().toString()
            if (errorBody.isNotEmpty()) {
                toLog("ApiException: $errorBody")
            }
            try {
                errorResponse = GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(errorBody, ErrorResponse::class.java)
                errorResponse?.toString() ?: errorBody

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                response.raw().message()
            }
        }
        return ApiException(message, errorResponse, ApiError.HTTP, exception)
    }

    fun network(exception: IOException): ApiException {
        return ApiException(exception.message ?: "network", null, ApiError.NETWORK, exception)
    }

    fun parse(exception: JsonSyntaxException): ApiException {
        return ApiException(exception.message ?: "parse", null, ApiError.CONVERSION, exception)
    }

    fun unknown(exception: Throwable): ApiException {
        return ApiException(exception.message ?: "unknown", null, ApiError.UNKNOWN, exception)
    }

    fun timeout(exception: SocketTimeoutException): ApiException {
        return ApiException("Connection timed out", null, ApiError.TIMEOUT_EXCEPTION, exception)
    }
}
}
```

And when calling request

```
yourRequest.compose { observable ->
                observable.retryWhen { flow ->
                    flow.ofType(ApiException::class.java).flatMap {
                        when {
                            it.error == ApiError.TIMEOUT_EXCEPTION -> Flowable.empty<T>()
                            it.error == ApiError.NETWORK           -> getSnackBarFlowable().flatMap { if (it) Flowable.just(it) else Flowable.empty<T>() }

                            else                                   -> Flowable.error(it)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.subscribe({}, {})
```

getSnackBarFlowable() is get from fragment. you can use something else

```
fun getSnackBarFlowable(): Flowable<Boolean> = Flowable.create({ subscriber ->
    if (view == null) {
        subscriber.onNext(false)

    } else {
        val snackBar = Snackbar.make(activity!!.currentFocus, R.string.error_connection_fail, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
        snackBar.setAction("Retry") { subscriber.onNext(true) }
        snackBar.show()
    }
}, LATEST)
```

I know, quite enough of code. But this solution is really helpful for me in different projects